# What is the number of seating plans?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am reading a book and there was a topic regarding number of sitting arrangements in a wedding.

The information provided is:

- 107 people.
- 11 tables.
- Each table can accommodate up to 10 people.
- The order in each table *does* matter but the order of tables does *not*.

The author finally said that "there are about $11^{107}$ possible seating plans."

Isn't this incorrect since it allows for repetition? My answer would be that the number of seating plans is $110 \choose x_1,...,x_{11}$ such that $x_i = 10$ with $i \in$ {1,...,11}.

Can anyone suggest a correct solution to this problem?

P.S. The book is called "Algorithms to Live By" by Brian Christian and Tom Griffiths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$11^{107}$ would be the answer if you could assign each person any of the $11$ tables. That means that the tables have no limit on the number of people seated at them, that the seating order around the table does not matter, but the order of the tables does.

When everyone is seated there are $3$ empty seats. It is easiest to introduce $3$ dummy people to fill those seats, and remove them afterwards. So we simply have $110$ people, of which $3$ are identical dummies.

There are $110!$ ways to order all the people. The first $10$ go in order around the first table, the next $10$ around the next table, and so on. Some of these seating arrangements are considered the same, so you now just have to work out how often each arrangement has been overcounted.

The order of the $11$ tables do not matter, so this gives a factor of $11!$ by which we overcounted. Also, the three dummy people that stand in for the empty seats must also be considered the same for a factor of $3!$. This leaves a total of $\frac{110!}{11!3!}$ arrangements.

Note that if we only care about the relative positions of the people seated around a table, then rotation of a table seating does not matter. If that is the case, then you would divide by a further factor of $10^{11}$. Even in this case, the $11^{107}$ estimate is far too low.

Comment: I see, so my answer would mean that neither the order of the people in a table mattered nor the order of the tables, right?

Comment: @alexandrosangeli Almost. $110 \choose {10,...,10}$ is the number of ways to split 110 people into 11 distinct groups of 10. So there the order of the 11 groups/tables does matter (and order within a group around each table does not, as you said).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the order of tables does matter?

Comment: @alexandrosangeli ${110 \choose {10,...,10}} = {110 \choose 10}{100 \choose 10}{90 \choose 10}...{10 \choose 10}$ It's the number of ways to choose 10 people for the first table, times the number of ways to choose 10 people for the next table, etc. If the tables had different sizes it would be obvious that the tables are distinguishable in this calculation. To make the table order not matter you have to divide by a factor of $11!$. Note that the denominator of ${110 \choose {10,...,10}}$ only has the eleven factors $10!$ for rearranging the people at each of the 11 tables.

Comment: Thanks, your comment about not being obvious because all tables hold the same number of people helped me understand this. (For example $5 \choose 1$ $\cdot$ $4 \choose 3$  $\neq$  $5 \choose 3$ $\cdot$  $4 \choose 1$

Comment: An additional complication is that the tables with dummies may not actually have empty seats. But calculating that gets messy. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't understand what you mean. There are 110 seats, and 107 people plus 3 dummies. So there are no empty seats until we remove the 3 dummies at the end to create the empty seats.

Comment: I'm saying that those empty seats may not actually exist. Let's say we have a table with 7 real people named A to G, plus 3 dummies named Z. If we have empty seats then ABCDEFGZZZ is a different arrangement to ABCZDEFZGZ, but if the empty seats don't exist then those two arrangements are identical.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, I see. That would involve a bit of case work, but it is not too bad as there are only 3 "empty seats" to take care of and they can only be distributed in 3 essentially different ways: 1+1+1, 1+2,  or 3. Just consider those tables to have a smaller capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the authors of *Algorithms to Live By*, and your question came up in my Google alerts. I love that you're engaging so deeply with the book, and wanted to add a couple quick thoughts.

First of all, the wedding that Tom and I are discussing is that of Meghan Bellows and her husband J. D. Luc Peterson. The bride and groom published a delightful paper about how they formalized and solved their wedding seating-chart problem, called "Finding an optimal seating chart" (2012), which I encourage you to check out: https://www.improbable.com/news/2012/Optimal-seating-chart.pdf.

The figure that Tom and I cite comes directly from their paper: "There are a total of $11^{107} = 2.69 × 10^{111}$ combinations for seating guests at the various tables."

I must point out that in both their paper and our book, it is *not* stated, as you write, that, "The order in each table does matter but the order of tables does not." In fact, the opposite assumptions are made to get the $11^{107}$ figure: namely, that order within a table does *not* matter, but the tables themselves *are* distinct.

Honestly, I think your assumptions are more realistic!

But that is not the set of assumptions that Bellows & Peterson use in arriving at their $11^{107}$ figure.

As both you and Jaap discuss, the number of combinations is much greater under your formulation, where order around a table is taken into account. (This may be why Bellows and Peterson did not formulate the problem this way, even though it's intuitive to do so! It is also common at weddings to allow guests to choose their own seats around the table, rather than to have specific place settings. So, that part of the optimization problem is offloaded onto the guests.)

Under this set of assumptions, as you and Jaap note, the figure of $11^{107}$ is too high, because it does not factor into account the maximum capacity of each table. Tom and I mention this in the endnotes for this chapter. However, I seem to recall from talking with Meghan that they relaxed their maximum-capacity constraint on purpose when they ran their mixed-integer linear optimization.

Hope this is helpful to you. I love the discussion on this page!

Comment: I really appreciate replying to my question and I want to say that I am enjoying your book so far! Regarding the problem: I must've misinterpreted the meaning of the word "pair" in the book ("If a particular pair of people didn't know one another, they got 0...") and assumed that the order in a table was indeed significant (assuming these pairs **must** sit next to each other). I also assumed that the number of arrangements was derived while accounting for the maximum capacity of each table. $11^{107}$ makes much more sense now. Thanks for making it clear!

Comment: Apparently relaxing the constraints seems to multiply the number of possibilities by just over a million

Answer (score 0):

$11^{107}\approx 2.7\times 10^{111}$ would be the number of ways of allocating $107$ distinct people to $11$ distinct tables, where they later find their own seat at the table.  But it allows up to $107$ people at a single table when in fact the number is restricted to $10$ each.

$\dfrac{110!}{{(10!)}^{11}} \approx 1.1\times10^{106}$ would be the number of ways of allocating $110$ distinct people to $11$ distinct tables with $10$ people at each table, again leaving them to find their seats later.  But this is too high as we only have $107$ people, so we need a slightly more detailed calculation depending on the distribution of the three empty places:

- If there is an empty place at three tables then the number of ways is ${11 \choose 3}\frac{107!}{{(10!)}^{8}(9!)^{3}}$
- If there are three empty places at one table then the number of ways is ${11 \choose 1}\frac{107!}{{(10!)}^{10}(7!)^{1}}$
- If there are two empty places at one table and one at at another then the number of ways is ${11 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}\frac{107!}{{(10!)}^{9}(9!)^{1}(8!)^{1}}$

We can add those three possibilities to answer the original question as $$\frac{107!}{{(10!)}^{11}}(165000+7920+99000)\approx 2.3 \times 10^{105
}$$

which is just under a millionth of the original $11^{107}$.

Comment: If the tables were not distinguishable, the correct count would be obtained by dividing your count by $11!$, yielding $5.8 \times 10^{97}$ and matching my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074733/there-were-107-people-at-the-wedding-and-11-tables-which-could-accommodate/4074966#4074966).