Is this comment in the book Algorithms to live by correct?
I am reading the book "Algorithms to live by" by Brian Christian and Tom Griffiths. In chapter 8: Relaxation: Let it slide, I saw one problem and its number of solution which seems wrong to me. Quoting from Page 169.

There were 107 people at the wedding and 11 tables, which could accommodate ten people each. This means there were about $11^{107}$ possible seating plans: that's a 112-digit number, more than 200 billion googols, a figure that dwarfs the (merely 80-digit) number of atoms in the observable universe.

Now, I doubt this estimate. By saying total number of seating arrangement is $11^{107}$, it is possible when each table has option to sit at any of the 107 people. But it is not as each table has capacity to sit only 10. So, it should be less than this, right?

Emphasis on the fact that it is an estimate.  It will still be within a few orders of magnitude of this answer.

I will point out that the estimate and full calculation by @Toby both assume 1) The tables are labeled and it matters to us which table each person is at (e.g. tables closer to the bride/groom are more prestigious). 2) Exact positioning within a table is not important. In alternate phrasings of the problem, we could have not cared which table number is used for each table, caring only who is at what tables... affecting the final total, but still having it be an absurdly large number.

$11^{107}$ would be if each person has a choice of which of the eleven tables to sit at (and it doesn't matter how they are arranged at the table) which wouldn't really work (as once ten people choose a table noone else can fit).  My instinct is that there are $110$ seats there are $\frac {110!}{3!}$ ways the 107 people can choose their seats. To me position within a table and which table matter (although it could be argued rotational orientation doesn't matter).  Anyhow... it's an informally worded problem so there's no right answer. (Although I just don't see the given).

See related discussion in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010654/what-is-the-number-of-seating-plans

The key word is "about":

This means there were about $11^{107}$ possible seating plans$\dots$

Sometimes in combinatorics, the true number of arrangements is well-approximates by assuming that certain things can be done independently. So here, we are assuming that each person can independently choose a table, without worrying if other peoples' choices made that table full. The author is using this technique.

JMoravitz computed the actual correct number in a comment. I reproduce his work below.
There are many possible distributions for the number of people at each table. You just need a list of $11$ numbers which add up to $107$, where all the numbers are at most $10$. One example is
$$
[10,10,10,8,10,10,10,10,10,9,10]
$$
For each particular distribution, the number of ways to assign the people to tables which achieve that distribution is given by a multinomial coefficient. For the distribution above, the number of ways is
$$
\frac{107!}{10!\cdot 10!\cdot 10!\cdot 8!\cdot 10!\cdot 10!\cdot 10!\cdot 10!\cdot 10!\cdot 9!\cdot 10!}
$$
To find the total number of ways, you just to take the sum of these multinomial coefficients over all possible distributions. Fortunately, there are not too many cases, up to symmetry.

There are $\binom{11}3$ distributions that have three tables of $9$.

There are $11\cdot 10$ distributions which have one table of $8$, and one table of $9$.

There are $11$ distributions which have a single table of $7$.


Therefore, the total number of distributions is
$$
\binom{11}3\cdot \frac{107!}{(10!)^8\cdot 9!^3}
+11\cdot 10\cdot \frac{107!}{(10!)^9\cdot 9!\cdot 8!}
+11\cdot  \frac{107!}{(10!)^{10}\cdot 7!}\approx 2.32\cdot 10^{105}
$$
The author's approximation was $11^{107}\approx 2.67\cdot 10^{111}$. This means that the approximation was only off by a factor of about $10^6$, or one million.
